# merge puppet code in manifest file

Tags: puppet

I am using puppet 3.8.7.I want to write all of the below code in a single manifest file and run it.every code works fine separately.is it possible? first, I want to install nodejs,then update my nodejs, then run my bashscript,then install git and download git repo

install nodejs:

```
class { 'nodejs':
  repo_url_suffix => '6.x',
}
```

then update node js:

```
exec { 'install-node-version-manager':
cwd       => '/',
path      => '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin',
logoutput => 'on_failure',
command   => 'npm install -g n',
}


exec { 'install-node-version-manager':
cwd       => '/',
path      => '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin',
logoutput => 'on_failure',
command   => 'n latest',

}
```

then run bash_script.sh

```
file {'/home/ec2-user/my_bash_script.sh':
 source => "puppet:///modules/mymodule/my_bash_script.sh",
 mode => '755',

}

exec {'/home/ec2-user/my_bash_script.sh':
    refreshonly => 'true',
    require => File["/home/ec2-user/my_bash_script.sh"],
    subscribe => File["/home/ec2-user/my_bash_script.sh"],
  }
```

then install git and download repo

```
package 
    { 'git':
      ensure => 'latest',
    }

vcsrepo { "/nodejs-helloworld":
        ensure   => latest,
        provider => git,
        require  => [ Package["git"] ],
        source   => "git@gitlab.dev.abc.net:hello-world/nodejs-helloworld.git",
        revision => 'master',
}
```

Comment: Despite style and efficiency issues, the substance of all of this is completely fine. Why not just put all of this in a single manifest and specify dependencies as you want?

Comment: @Ishwarya, Have you tried it?

Comment: yes i tried it,putting everything in a single manifest file worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puppet provides various ways to establish relationships and ordering between resources.
You can use meta-parameters - require, before, notify, subscribe for example. You can also use chaining arrows to control the flow of the execution.
here your code, in one module -

```
 class installnodejs{

  class { 'nodejs':
    repo_url_suffix => '6.x',
    before          => Exec['install-node-version-manager-global'],
  }

  exec { 'install-node-version-manager-global':
    cwd       => '/',
    path      => '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin',
    logoutput => 'on_failure',
    command   => 'npm install -g n',
    before    => Exec['install-node-version-manager-latest'],
  }

  exec { 'install-node-version-manager-latest':
    cwd       => '/',
    path      => '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin',
    logoutput => 'on_failure',
    command   => 'n latest',
    before    => File['/home/ec2-user/my_bash_script.sh'],
  }

  file {'/home/ec2-user/my_bash_script.sh':
    source => "puppet:///modules/mymodule/my_bash_script.sh",
    mode   => '755',
    before => Exce['/home/ec2-user/my_bash_script.sh'], 
  }

  exec {'/home/ec2-user/my_bash_script.sh':
    refreshonly => 'true',
    require   => File["/home/ec2-user/my_bash_script.sh"],
    subscribe => File["/home/ec2-user/my_bash_script.sh"],
    before    => Vcsrepo['/nodejs-helloworld'],
  }

  package { 'git':
    ensure => 'latest',
  }

  vcsrepo { "/nodejs-helloworld":
    ensure   => latest,
    provider => git,
    require  => [ Package["git"] ],
    source   => "git@gitlab.dev.uberops.net:hello-world/nodejs-helloworld.git",
    revision => 'master',
  }

}
```

please notice that I've changed the names of your resources. you can't include the same resource twice in the same module.